# Bootstrap column grid issue

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, render

I have a question regarding Bootstrap (v3.3.1). I've created a page with a navbar, one row, and four columns. It works great, except in IE8. I've attached images of how it looks when it works, and how it works when I open it in IE8 - any help would be greatly appreciated! As you can see, the text from the 2nd column is visible over the 3rd and the first two columns are pretty much missing from view. Inside the boxes with the label "text" are simple accordions which use the collapse function.

I have some links to images below:

[Working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BANtF.png)

[Not working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyBVd.png)

**--Update--**
My heading already has this part:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

So all I have to do is delete these two lines from and it should work?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support media queries, which are used to create Bootstraps responsive grid. You can however use a JavaScript polyfill called Respond.js to add this.

See the Bootstrap documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs for more details.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. I read that and looked at Respond.js. Is there a simple guide to explain how to activate/implement this script on my site? Thank you!

Comment: You only have to link the script in the `<head>` tag of your page. Take a look at the template at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template to see how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks, so if I'm understanding correctly, all I have to do is delete the two lines that are already in my heading? I updated the original post with the specifics. THank you again ckuijjer.

Comment: No, your heading looks good. The `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` is a trick to only add the script if Internet Explorer has a version less than 9. Bootstraps documentation talks about Respond.js not working when serving your page from the filesystem instead of from a webserver. Might this be the case?

Comment: That does indeed look like the problem! I am marking this as answered, however do you know of any workarounds for this issue or places I can go for additional information to remedy this problem?

Comment: Respond.js works by requesting the css file using ajax, the javascript in a browser isn't allowed to touch your filesystem (as you don't want every website to be able to read your harddrive). I think the only solution is to use a small webserver when developing.  https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/ might be a simple one for windows.